# Cron job to kill all hanging docker containers

Tags: docker

I am new to docker containers but we have containers being deployed and due to some internal application network bugs the process running in the container hangs and the docker container is not terminated. While we debug this issue I would like a way to find all those containers and setup a cron job to periodically check and kill those relevant containers.

So how would I determine from "docker ps -a" which containers should be dropped and how would I go about it? Any ideas? We are eventually moving to kubernetes which will help with these issues.

Comment: How do *you* know a container is hanging? You can run lots of different apps in a container, so there's no generic answer to this for any app that anyone could run. With that detail, you can define health checks in the image, or liveness and readiness probes in Kubernetes.

Comment: Due to the expected time a process should run. The max would be an hour but like I said we are debugging this but to avoid open file connections increasing I have to kill those that are active for too long and not being removed. Thanks for responding.

Comment: You are right though; setting up the process to do heartbeat checks would be best approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docker already have a command to cleanup the docker environment, you can use it manually or maybe setup a job to run the following command:

```
$ docker system prune
```

> Remove all unused containers, networks, images (both dangling and
>   unreferenced), and optionally, volumes.

refer to the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/system_prune/) for more details on advanced usage.

Comment: This would remove a stopped container, not a running container with a hung app inside of it.

Comment: yes was about to type that...I guess I will have to wait on finding the bug or setup a hearbeat check. Just thought to ask and perhaps someone had a smart idea or workaround.

Comment: yes, I just noticed that the question is about the hanging app, but thats then is the app issue, where it should have a mechanism to recover once it fails.